# Cannot satisfy both Checkstyle ModifierOrder and FinalParameters with parameter annotations

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am using Checkstyle 6.12. I want to use both of these modules:

```
<module name="ModifierOrder"/>
<module name="FinalParameters"/>
```

I have a method that looks like this

```java
@GET
@Path("{thingId}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getThing(
    final @PathParam("thingId") String thingId,
) {
  return "halp meh";
}
```

If I run Checkstyle on this I get an output like this:

```xml
<checkstyle version="6.12">
  <error line="17" column="13" severity="error" 
      message="'@PathParam' annotation modifier does not precede non-annotation modifiers." 
      source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.modifier.ModifierOrderCheck"/>
  ...
```

If I take away the `final` modifier, I still get an error:

```xml
<checkstyle version="6.12">
  <error line="17" column="7" severity="error" 
      message="Parameter version should be final." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.FinalParametersCheck"/>
```

This kind of puts me in an awkward situation, as I would like use both of these to enforce some code style on the code I am writing. Is there a way to configure Checkstyle to work in this situation?

Comment: Can you not do `@PathParam("thingId") final String thingId`?

Comment: @awksp Oh god, well this is embarrassing... I "did" that and I got a compiler error. I didn't realize I had `@PathParam("thingId") final @PathParam("thingId")`. There were 2 of them so that was what the problem was :(.

Comment: :P Hey, that kind of thing happens to everyone. At least it's solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [awks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3580294/awksp) pointed out, moving the annotation before the `final` works.

```
@PathParam("thingId") final String thingId
```

The reason I didn't notice this was because when I tried to do that, I received a compiler error. The problem was that I had the annotation duplicated in there twice:

```
@PathParam("thingId") final @PathParam("thingId")
```